# Power BI What if analysis

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a matrix Power BI visualization which is like

```
       Jan Feb Mar April
Client1 10 20  30  10
Client2 15 25  65  80
Client3 66 22  54  12
```

I have created 3 what if parameters slicer table (having values from 1 to 4) for each client

For example, If the value of the first slicer is 1 and the second is 2 and the third is 2 then I want

```
       Jan Feb Mar April
Client1 0  20  30  10
Client2 0  0   65  80
Client3 0  0   54  12
```

That is, it should replace the value with zero. I have been able to achieve that for one client using Dateadd function (by adding month)

```
Measure  = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Value]), 
               DATEADD('Table'[Column], Parameter[Parameter Value], MONTH))
```

and I have used this measure to display the value, but how to make it work for the other two clients as well .

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have three parameter tables as follows

```
Parameter1  Parameter2  Parameter3

Value1      Value2      Value3
------      ------      ------
1           1           1
2           2           2
3           3           3
4           4           4
```

and each of them has its own slicer. Then the measure you are after might look something like this:

```
Measure = 
    VAR Val1 = MAX(Parameter1[Value1])
    VAR Val2 = MAX(Parameter2[Value2])
    VAR Val3 = MAX(Parameter3[Value3])
    VAR CurrClient = MAX('Table'[Client])
    VAR CurrMonth = MONTH(DATEVALUE(MAX('Table'[Month]) & " 1, 2000"))
    RETURN SWITCH(CurrClient,
               "Client1", IF(CurrMonth <= Val1, 0, SUM('Table'[Value])),
               "Client2", IF(CurrMonth <= Val2, 0, SUM('Table'[Value])),
               "Client3", IF(CurrMonth <= Val3, 0, SUM('Table'[Value])),
               SUM('Table'[Value])
           )
```

Basically, you read in each parameter and compare them to the month in the current cell.